# Validating for JavaScript error via Selenium Webdriver

Tags: javascript, ruby, selenium, webdriver

Is there such ability to validate for JavaScript errors on the page via Selenium WebDriver using Ruby?

Answer (score 1):

If you attach to `window.onerror`, you can record errors that happen on the page, execute your test, and read any results. Something like this:

```
driver.execute_script("window._errors = [];"
driver.execute_script("window.onerror = function(){window._errors.push(arguments);};")
//do your test...
errors = driver.execute_script("return window._errors;")
```

https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/RubyBindings

This keeps everything isolated in your test, however you might miss errors that occur before your inject your listener. You may want to consider using a JavaScript Error Monitoring service like [TrackJS](https://trackjs.com/) to always listen for errors, and then attach to the history to assert your test passes.

Comment: I have no access to JS code, so TrackJS is out of picture. However, code, if I am not doing anything, just like driver.navigate to the page, will work?